# The remote server returned an error : (401) Unauthorized - PowerShell - Microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the list of all groups where the resourceProvisioningOptions = Team, here is the url which gets all the data through API call:

```
$clientID = xxxx
$tenantName = xxxx
$ClientSecret = xxxx
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"


$ReqTokenBody = @{
Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
client_Id     = $clientID
Client_Secret = $clientSecret 
} 

$authheader = @{

    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"
    'Content-Type'='application\json'

}

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

$test = "'Team'"

$apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq {0})' -f $test

$Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $authheader -Body $ReqTokenBody -Method Get


$Groups = ($Data | select-object Value).Value | Select-Object  displayName, id, description, mail | Out-File .\texxtfile.txt
```

However, I am getting a 401 error when I try to run the script even though I have all the permissions required to make the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have picked application permissions in your AAD application. There is an additioanl step. You will need to admin consent your application in the app registration portal to use Group.Read.All to run this. If you have not done this in the UI this will fail.

Comment: I have Delegate Permissions and Have I have both Group.Read.All and Group.ReadWrite.All granted for my tenant.

Comment: If you are using delegated permissions...then have you gone through the ui consent flow for it for that user you are using?
For powershell, its really recommended that you use application permissions (app-only). We are in early preview of a PowerShell SDK. You may want to try this out instead, it uses Device Code flow that really helps with the sign in and consent of this flow in PowerShell https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Yes, using the Device Code Flow, I can get the required information I want and my script is running fine. However, using client_credentials and after making changes in the API permission, I am still getting 401 unauthorized code after enabling application permission for Groups/

Comment: After working around the code, I stopped getting 401 error but end up getting 400 error.